# Overwriting a Shortcode

Tags: php, functions, shortcode, post-thumbnails, content

I have a theme that extends the Visual Composer plugin with a slider on the front page. The slider will show five testimonials from five different customers. I want to add the featured image of each testimonial as the thumbnail in the slider.

Here's the shortened code from the parent theme:

```
function jo_customers_testimonials_slider( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array( 'limit' => 5, "widget_title" => __('What Are People Saying', 'jo'), 'text_color' => "#000" ), $atts ) );
    $content = "";
    $loopArgs = array( "post_type" => "customers", "posts_per_page" => $limit, 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1 );

    $postsLoop = new WP_Query( $loopArgs );
    $content = "";

    $content .= '...';
    $content .= '...';
    $content .= '...';

    wp_reset_query();
    return $content;
}
add_shortcode( 'jo_customers_testimonials_slider', 'jo_customers_testimonials_slider' );
```

My functions.php file:

```
function jo_customers_testimonials_slider_with_thumbnail( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array( 'limit' => 5, "widget_title" => __('What Are People Saying', 'jo'), 'text_color' => "#000" ), $atts ) );
    $content = "";
    $loopArgs = array( "post_type" => "customers", "posts_per_page" => $limit, 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1 );

    $postsLoop = new WP_Query( $loopArgs );
    $content = "";

    $content .= '...';
    $content .= get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), 'thumbnail' );
    $content .= '...';
    $content .= '...';

    wp_reset_query();
    return $content;
}
add_shortcode( 'jo_customers_testimonials_slider', 'jo_customers_testimonials_slider_with_thumbnail' );
```

In theory, the function from my functions.php file should overwrite the shortcode from the parent theme. But nothing seems to happen when I use this code. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

Tried this code, but it still won't work.

```
function wpa_add_child_shortcodes(){
remove_shortcode('jo_customers_testimonials_slider');
    add_shortcode( 'jo_customers_testimonials_slider', 'jo_customers_testimonials_slider_with_thumbnail' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpa_add_child_shortcodes' );
```

Also changed 

`add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpa_add_child_shortcodes' );` to 

`add_action( 'init', 'wpa_add_child_shortcodes' );`

, but no difference in the outcome.

**Edit 2 (With Solution):**

Changing `add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpa_add_child_shortcodes' );` to `add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'wpa_add_child_shortcodes' );` solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A child theme's `functions.php` file is loaded *before* the parent theme's, so the behavior you're seeing is correct.

Try adding your shortcode on a later action instead:

```
function wpa_add_child_shortcodes(){
    add_shortcode( 'jo_customers_testimonials_slider', 'jo_customers_testimonials_slider_with_thumbnail' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpa_add_child_shortcodes' );
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. This seems to not work either. Good try though.

Comment: does the parent theme add the shortcode on an action? I've tested this and confirmed working in twentythirteen child theme, so there's something particular about your theme that's preventing this from working.

Comment: Nope. `add_shortcode('jo_customers_testimonials_slider', 'jo_customers_testimonials_slider');` is all it does.

Comment: have you tried modifying your shortcode to return something obvious to confirm it's not actually working and the problem is within your own shortcode handler? otherwise I would have to see your parent and child themes in their entirety to tell you why it's not working.

Comment: Yes, I added `<span id="test"></span>` into the post content. It doesn't show at all.